# prevent background window scroll up to the top when other window popup in angular 7/8

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular7, angular8

so I have a pop window that open in the mid of the page when I click a  tag, however, the background window always scroll all the way to the top when the popup window display. I want the background page don't scroll all the way up and just stay where is it. Below are by code

HTML

```
<div class="notSU">
  <a (click)="open()">open popup window</a>
</div>
```

javascript (ts file)

```
open(){
 const window: WindowRef = this.windowService.open({
          title: 'My Window',
          content: 'My Content!',
          width: 450,
          height: 200
      });

      window.result.subscribe((result) => {
          if (result instanceof WindowCloseResult) {
              console.log('Window was closed!');
          }
      });
}
```

CSS

```
.notSU{
   overflow:hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your modal window code is located at the top of the page, and the position is set to relative or absolute, that may possibly be why it scrolls to the top. Try giving `.notSU` these css settings below. `position: fixed;` positions the element relative to the browser window, vs a parent it might be nestled in.

```css
.notSU {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 400;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50% -50%);
  max-width: 450px;
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```